# Объект в объекте, ограничение доступа

Tags: java, android

```
public class Thing implements Parcelable{

public List<String> mFotos; 


public Thing(ArrayList<String> fotos){
    if (fotos == null) mFotos = new FotoList();
    else mFotos = new FotoList(fotos);
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы доступ к методом объекта `mFotos` был, а ссылку на объект `mFotos`, созданный в конструкторе, был запрет. Ну то есть нельзя присвоить другую ссылку переменной `mFotos`, а к методом обращаться можно:

```
thing.mFotos.add("Строка");
```

Comment: объявите mFotos как final.

Comment: Блин, точно ведь. Ведь это же обычная переменная. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Еще вы можете продублировать все методы mFotos в классе thing таким образом:    `public void add(String s) {mFotos.add(s);}`

Comment: Об этом я думал, но это выглядит как-то громоздко и неправильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ключевое слова `final` обеспечивает сохранность переменной от изменений. Если изначально не присвоено ни какого значения, то остается возможность присвоить значение переменной, но только один раз.

```
public class Thing implements Parcelable{

public final List<String> mFotos; 


public Thing(ArrayList<String> fotos){
    if (fotos == null) mFotos = new FotoList();
    else mFotos = new FotoList(fotos);
}
```

После того как в конструкторе переменной `mFotos` будет присвоена ссылка на объект, другую ссылку в переменную уже не запишешь.